# getElementsByClassName How to get html elements with links？

Tags: javascript

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("tag")[0];
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
var i = 0;
while (i < classname.length) {
  console.log(classname[i].innerText);
  i++
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="display:none">
  <div id="tagBall1" class="tagBall">
    <a href='/tags.php?/While/' class="tag">While</a>
    <a href='/tags.php?/return/' class="tag">return</a>
    <a href='/tags.php?/htaccess/' class="tag">htaccess</a>
    <a href='/tags.php?/' class="tag">CSS</a>
    <a href='/tags.php?/' class="tag">algorithm</a>
    <a href='/tags.php?/let/' class="tag">let</a>
    <a href='/tags.php?/SEO/' class="tag">SEO</a>
  </div>
  <p class="tag">2021.1.25</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the class element of a tag, but I get the result that it loses its link. How can I avoid it losing its link

Answer (score 0):

To select all links just select all the a tags. Then filter out whichever has your classes and then just get the `href`(or the links) by using a map.

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
var tagsWithYourClass = aTags.filter(tag=> tag.matches('.tag') )
var links = tagsWithYourClass.map(tag=> tag.getAttribute("href"))
```

Otherwise better way is

```
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll("a.tag").map(tag=>tag.href)
```